# NoClassDefFoundError upgrading project from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1

Tags: grails

I'm tryng  to upgrade a project from grails 2.1.0 to grails 2.1.1 but running it I got

```
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/dom/svg/SVGOMDocument
```

But the batik jar are correctly in lib folder, compiling it with 2.1.0 works so I think there is
a classpath problem in 2.1.1 on MAC.

Already tried:

delete target dir
delete ivy-cache dir
do a grails clean
do a grails compile --refresh-dependencies

P.S. I have a xerces_2_5_0.jar in the /lib folder. I see that in 2.1.1 was fixed something about xerces, can be relate to my problem? http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8819

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you tried `grails clean` and/or deleting the `target` directory in your app?

Comment: Yes, already tried. And if I downgrade to 2.1.0 the project still compile and run good. I'm confused.

Comment: Long time ago of course, but do you recall if/how you got this sorted out?

Comment: @Madbreaks Honestly no...